# Function gets called before form code is executed/shown

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making an application that will automatically transfer a folder to a specific place (in my case it will be a USB-drive).
I want the radiobuttons to change colors to know whether or not it is transfering, but the function "DirectoryCopy" is somehow getting executed before the form is updated with the radioButton colors.

```
radioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Green; //igang
radioButton2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
  try {
    Console.WriteLine("Transfering newFolder.");
    DirectoryCopy(@"Some\path\for\a\folder", @"" + Convert.ToString(d.Name) + "newFolder", true);
    } catch {
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
    }
```

Comment: Try putting a MessageBox after setting radioButton2.ForeColor and see the behaviour.

Comment: In addition to @TheShooter's suggestion, try `radioButton2.Invalidate(); radioButton2.Update()` or either one after changing the color. It forces the display to redraw itself.

Comment: Work like a charm! Thank you @KeyurPATEL and The Shooter

Comment: Do you want to answer the post so I can confirm the solution? @KeyurPATEL